# How to give the datas from eventSources to the EventListener

Tags: javascript, symfony, event-listener, server-sent-events

I'm loading an EventListener used for FullCalendar for each calendar on my website. The problem is that sometimes I need to change the "method" of rendering events (depending on the URL).
I would like to pass it by eventSources and be able to take back the URL in the EventListener. I tried to put something in data without any success..

On calendar-settings.js I've this call :

```
eventSources: [
 {
    url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loader'),
    type: 'POST',
    // A way to add custom filters to your event listeners
    data: {
    },
    error: function() {
        //alert('There was an error while fetching Google Calendar!');
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSE does not support sending POST data.

Basically you will have to send your parameters using GET.

Alternatives would be to send it first using an AJAX call (and store it in the PHP session for instance, ready for your SSE handler to use it), or to put the data in a cookies (SSE does support cookies, but only if not relying on CORS: CORS and cookies clash, and cookies lose.) Or fall back on using XHR instead of SSE.

But GET sounds best for you, as the data sounds relatively short and not privacy critical (i.e. it is not a password).

(Quick plug: all the above topics are covered in depth in ch.9 of my book, Data Push Apps With HTML5 SSE.)

Comment: Nice, didn't thought about this, I'll try to give a variable or not by GET ! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

So I had to change a bit my EventSource and it worked with :

`eventSources: [
            {
                url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loader'),
                type: 'GET',
                // A way to add custom filters to your event listeners
                data: {
                    Information : "value"
                },
                error: function() {
                   //alert('There was an error while fetching Google Calendar!');
                }
            }
        ]`

and I added a route :

`<route id="fullcalendar_loader_{Information}" pattern="/fc-load-events/{Information}">
   <default key="_controller">ADesignsCalendarBundle:Calendar:loadCalendar</default>
   <option key="expose">true</option>
</route>`

Hope it will work for you to if you have the same problem :)